# PHP regex select word that contain specific character from string

Tags: php, regex, laravel

000001  0001    000000000000001975                  00  02  0   000 2017/12/13 14:13:27

i m developing a system with laravel.
this is the string i get from a csv file. i need to select this date and time. into an array. if i can select word that contain : (14:13:27) i can get time and same method to date.

Comment: `strpos($string_from_csv, $string_to_check);`

Comment: i want to get  (14:13:27) word from (000001 0001 000000000000001975 00 02 0 000 2017/12/13 14:13:27) string

Comment: if you exploded on space you would have an easy array to work with

Comment: i did but in the generated array time is not in the dame array element all the time. some time its in 12th element some time in 13 element. that''s why i planed to do it with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
/(\d{4}\/[^ ]+) \K([\d:]+)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4dF9/3)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be -

```
$string= "000001 0001 000000000000001975 00 02 0 000 2017/12/13 44:13:27";
preg_match("/([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/", $string, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unclear about the OP's exact desired output, but I was more-so underwhelmed by the patterns in the other answers.  I'll post this battery of solutions for the betterment of Stackoverflow since I couldn't find a suitable duplicate to close with.

I'm using the tildes `~` as pattern delimiters so that the `/` characters in the pattern don't need to be escaped.  Also, notice I am not calling `\K` to restart the fullstring match because there is no reason to do so.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a5e7eebcfa2fc6e5892c949c4b3f485378623a5))

```
$string='000001 0001 000000000000001975 00 02 0 000 2017/12/13 14:13:27';

var_export(preg_match('~\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}~',$string,$out)?$out:[]); // date
echo "\n\n";
var_export(preg_match('~\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~',$string,$out)?$out:[]); // time
echo "\n\n";
var_export(preg_match('~\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~',$string,$out)?$out:[]); // full datetime
echo "\n\n";
var_export(preg_match('~(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})~',$string,$out)?$out:[]); // capture date and time
echo "\n\n";
var_export(preg_match_all('~\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}|\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}~',$string,$out)?$out:[]); // capture date or time
echo "\n\n";
var_export(preg_match('~(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})~',$string,$out)?$out:[]); // capture date digits and time digits
```

Output:

```
// date
array (
  0 => '2017/12/13',
)

// time
array (
  0 => '14:13:27',
)

full date time
array (
  0 => '2017/12/13 14:13:27',
)

// capture date and time
array (
  0 => '2017/12/13 14:13:27',
  1 => '2017/12/13',
  2 => '14:13:27',
)

// capture date or time
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '2017/12/13',
    1 => '14:13:27',
  ),
)

// capture date digits and time digits
array (
  0 => '2017/12/13 14:13:27',
  1 => '2017',
  2 => '12',
  3 => '13',
  4 => '14',
  5 => '13',
  6 => '27',
)
```

p.s. For future readers, if you require stronger date validation than this, then regex is probably not the right tool for your task.